# Is it possible to prevent the debugger from attaching on Android?

Tags: android, security

I'm doing some reverse engineering protection on Android and I want to prevent debugging of the app. I know how to detect when a debugger is attached but is there a way to block it from attaching in first place?

Edit: For clarification and in response to droidpl's answer, I mean ways beyond just setting `debuggable=false` in the manifest in case the `.apk` is repacked.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can modify your build process to make your app not debuggable. In the `build.gradle` of your app, in the build type you want to avoid it to be debuggable, set the property `debuggable false`.

Now if you try to attach the debugger to your process, it won't appear in the running available processes.